# static block doesent show in email in magento

Tags: magento, static-block

I made a custom template in System->transactional email, I want to show expiration time of the order, I added a static block and when I preview the template works fine, but when I make an order it does not show in my the static block. Can anyone help me...'

Comment: Show your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the static block has the correct identifier, has the appropriate store-view and is enabled. If you use the format below, it should work:

```
 {{block type="cms/block" block_id="identifier_here"}}
```